# Stuck at shutdown after an ssd upgrade

Tags: debian, hard-disk, power-management, shutdown, nvme

I have replaced my sata ssd with an nvme one and after I installed the current stable debian 11, it turns out that my laptop doesn't shutdown.

What happens is I can see the systemd output saying that all is good, and when the final two lines appear:

```
...
[  OK  ] Reached target Power-Off.
[  numbers.numbers  ] reboot: Power down
```

the power button's led turns off, as if the computer was about to shut down, but the screen and the keyboard lights stay on.

I have found all in other problems that I should try to update my grub config by appending the flag `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` with `acpi=off`, `acpi=force`, `acpi=noirq`, or `noefi` but none of them solved the problem.

This happen to me on my thinkpad x1 4th gen.

Would you be able to help me figure out how to fix this? Thank you!

**EDIT**
I have installed the most recent kernel from the bullseye-backports and I have also upgraded both UEFI BIOS and SSD firmware with `fwupd`.

It looked like the computer shuts down as all lights and fan switch off, but when I try to switch it back on, by pressing the power button, it doesn't start. I have to hold the power button for a while to power off the system. Then I can start it again.

I have also tried to install the debian testing weekly, but this didn't help.

The [hardware website](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-carbon-type-20fb-20fc/20fc/20fcs1j302/r90kqwyx/downloads/ds111756-bios-update-utility-bootable-cd-for-windows-10-64-bit-81-64-bit-7-64-bit-32-bit-linux-thinkpad-x1-carbon-type-20fb-20fc-x1-yoga-types-20fq-20fr?Products=LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS%2FTHINKPAD-X-SERIES-LAPTOPS%2FTHINKPAD-X1-CARBON-TYPE-20FB-20FC%2F20FC%2F20FCS1J302%2FR90KQWYX) says that the latest UEFI BIOS upgrade v1.56, released in Dec 2022, will be the last one. Although I don't think that a month old upgrade is to blame.

[@oldfred](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/145882/oldfred), thank you for your helpful suggestion. Right now all is up to date:

```
~ $ sudo lshw  | grep -m 3 -A 8 "*-firmware"
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: LENOVO
          physical id: c
          version: N1FET82W (1.56 )
          date: 12/06/2022
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 16MiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi

~ $  udisksctl status
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Samsung SSD 980 PRO 500GB 5B2QGXA7  S5GYNX0T806688J      nvme0n1
```

Comment: Many issues, some seemingly not related are often solved with both UEFI & NVMe firmware updates.Compare vendors site's latest to: `sudo lshw | grep -m 1 -A 5 "*-firmware"` & 
`udisksctl status`